# Override a class from the bin folder

Tags: asp.net

Is there any way to provide a replacement class from a dll the bin folder? I want to replace the codebehind of a page written by a third party with my own implementation and don't have access to the source.

Comment: do you have access to the aspx page?

Comment: ah, and change the class it inherits from? clever ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have (at least) 2 possibilities:

1: Change .aspx file and change the *Inherits* attribute of the '<%@ Page' tag.

2: Use assembly redirection described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 2):

If it's .Net you can get the source with [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and rewrite it?

Comment: +1.  That should work.  Although I'm interested to see f anyone else comes up with an easier answer.

Comment: it's a mental big project with a lot of third (fourth?) party dependencies so i'd rather avoid that if at all possible. and i want the original supplier to be able to update their dll without us passing our code changes back to them.

Comment: If the OQ has access to the ASPX page, then the page's CodeBehind and InheritsFrom details can be changes to point to a differnet file and class. Shouldn't need to rework the original code, unless that's what's needed.